# MPU6050 Calibration

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, mpu6050

Why does the MPU6050 IMU sensor not require calibration? I've used other gyro sensors on RC helicopters that required calibration at boot. Also, how does it know what its neutral position is considering that I don't need to calibrate it?

Comment: it calibrates itself and as the datasheet says "Enhanced bias and sensitivity temperature stability reduces the need for user calibration".

Answer (score 2):

**It's not entirely true that it does not require any calibration at all.**

The MPU60X0 family's triple-axis MEMS gyroscope has certain features that **reduce** the need for calibration. These features are, as mentioned by Juraj, and on the datasheet:

- Enhanced bias
- Sensitivity temperature stability

This does not mean the sensor is 100% properly calibrated right out of the box, which means if you need it to be extremely accurate, you'd probably have to do some manual calibration on top of the built-in calibration features.

There is a discussion about this on this [Github issue](https://github.com/universam1/iSpindel/issues/6). I suggest reading up on that and you might be able to answer your own questions. They are also referring to [this datasheet](https://github.com/universam1/iSpindel/files/634097/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) (Direct Download).